# Register virtual sound device from within application

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I want to be able to process audio output of applications (VLC, Rhythmbox, ...) within my own one. Moreover, one should be able to select my application as the sink for the sound (e.g., in VLC or pavucontrol my application should appear as an output device).

How is this possible? Can it be done with ALSA, Pulseaudio, ...? Currently I am seeking for the easiest solution while later performant ones may become preferable. It would be great if most of the configuration could be done via API calls.

Thank you for your support!

Comment: You should have a look at JACK (http://jackaudio.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a PulseAudio module. There one can create own sinks and directly get access to the audio stream. Have a look at my implementation [here](https://github.com/saemy/pacc/blob/master/pa_module/pa_sink.cpp).